# OSX Yosemite - fstab not working - changing mount point

Tags: macos, mount, fstab

I am trying to set a different mountpoint for my external harddrive in osx yosemite. I have tried editing /etc/fstab using the following line (my external drive has no UUID so I can't use that):

```
LABEL=TOSHIBAEXT /users/username/mount/ ntfs rw
```

It does absolutely nothing. My system still mounts the drive in /Volumes. Afterwards, I tried the following line to test if fstab actually does anything:

```
LABEL=TOSHIBAEXT none ntfs rw,noauto
```

Again, nothing changes (it should not mount automatically using this line). I tried rebooting every time in-between.

I tried several other options I found using google but none of them did anything. At this point it looks to me like the fstab file is not used at all for some reason.

Thank you for your help.